# Executing Grails cron job at a certain time

Tags: grails, cron

I want to execute a cron job at a certain time (10pm) every day. Currently I am using following code but it is not working:

```
class ReviewBatchJob {

    private static final logger = LogFactory.getLog(this)

    def batchReviewScheduler
    static triggers = {
        cron cronExpression: "0 0 22 1/1 * ? *"
    }

    def execute() {
       batchReviewScheduler.reviewBatch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to use an expression of `0 0 22 * * ?`.

I'm assuming you're using the quartz plugin; if you don't have it installed, you'll need to. [Here's a good reference](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) with quartz cron expression examples.